# Having trouble using the export-csv

Tags: powershell, csv

I have 3 csv files and they are all only 1 column long. I have tried lots of thing to put it all in one csv file but i cant get it to work. When i output it, it all ends up in one column here is what i did so far

```
#Putting Csv files to Array    
$CSV1 = @(gc $EmailPathCsv)
$CSV2 = @(gc $UserLPathCsv)
$CSV3 = @(gc $EmailPathCsv)

#
for ($i=0; $i -lt $CSV1.Count; $i++) 
    {
    $CSV4 += $CSV1[$i] + "," + $CSV2[$i] + "," + $CSV3[$i] + " "
    }

$csv4 | out-file -append $MergedCsvExport
```

Comment: So, for example... you have 3 files with 10 entries and a header (I assume there is more). Are you looking to make 1 file with 1 header and 30 entries, or 3 headers and 10 rows with 3 columns each?

Comment: Nevermind, I just re-read your code. Try this... before your For loop, create $CSV4 as an empty array like `$CSV4 = @()` and then re-run it. I haven't tested it, but I bet that'll do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is adding everything into $CSV4, each time through the loop $CSV4 gets longer and longer.

Then you print it once. That's why you get one really long line. Try printing it once every time through the loop, and overwriting $CSV4 every time:

```
#Putting Csv files to Array    
$CSV1 = @(gc $EmailPathCsv)
$CSV2 = @(gc $UserLPathCsv)
$CSV3 = @(gc $EmailPathCsv)

#
for ($i=0; $i -lt $CSV1.Count; $i++) 
    {
    $CSV4 = $CSV1[$i] + "," + $CSV2[$i] + "," + $CSV3[$i] + " "
    out-file -InputObject $csv4 -Append -FilePath $MergedCsvExport
    }
```

Comment: That's a lot of extra leg work for what you're trying to accomplish. Change the whole For loop internal to: `$CSV1[$i] + "," + $CSV2[$i] + "," + $CSV3[$i]|out-file $MergedCsvExport -Append`

Comment: Your suggestion is nicer, but I was trying to achieve the smallest change to their code that would probably work, so it would still look familiar to the asker. I have tried to rewrite it completely, and I came up with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22725084/478656 ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a foromat string for that.

```
$CSV1 = @(gc $EmailPathCsv)
$CSV2 = @(gc $UserLPathCsv)
$CSV3 = @(gc $EmailPathCsv)

for ($i=0; $i -lt $CSV1.Count; $i++) 
 {
  '"{0}","{1}","{2}"' -f $CSV1[$i],$CSV2[$i],$CSV3[$i] |
   add-content $MergedCsvExport
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a more fun answer:

```powershell
$CSV1 = 1,2,3,4
$CSV2 = 10,11,12,13
$CSV3 = 'a','b','c','d'

$c = gv -Name CSV* | select -expand name | sort

(gv -Va $c[0])|%{$r=0}{@($c|%{(gv -Va $_)[$r]}) -join ',';$r++}
```

Sample output:

```powershell
1, 10, a
2, 11, b
3, 12, c
4, 13, d
```

You could put `|Out-File "merged-data.csv"` on the end to save to a file.

It works for more columns too, just add more arrays called `$CSV{something}`.

Edit: I wonder if Get-Variable's output is in a predictable order, or unspecified? If you don't mind if the column order might change, it collapses to:

```powershell
$CSV1 = 1,2,3,4
$CSV2 = 10,11,12,13
$CSV3 = 'a','b','c','d'

(gv CSV*)[0].Value|%{$r=0}{@((gv CSV*)|%{(gv -Va $_.Name)[$r]}) -join ',';$r++}
```

Edit again: Well, in case anyone notices and is curious, and has time on their hands, I've expanded it all out with an explanation of what it's doing:

```powershell
# Search the local variable scope for variables named CSV*
# This will find $CSV1, $CSV2, etc.
# This means the number of columns
# isn't fixed, you can easily add more.
# Take their names, sort them. 
# Result: an array of strings "CSV1", "CSV2", ...
# for however many variables there are
$columnVariables = Get-Variable -Name "CSV*" | Select-Object -Expand Name | Sort-Object

# NB. if you remove $CSV3= from your code, it is
# still in memory from previous run. To remove
# it, use `Remove-Variable "CSV3"

# In pseudo-code, what the next part does is
# for row in range(data):
#    @(CSV1[row], CSV2[row], ... CSVn[row]) -join ','

# The outer loop over the number of columns
# is done by piping something of the right length
# into a foreach loop, but ignoring the content.
# So get the first column array content:
$firstColumn = (Get-Variable $columnVariables[0]).Value

# and pipe it into a loop.
# The loop uses ForEach {setup} {loop} pattern 
# to setup a row-counter before the loop body
$firstColumn | ForEach { $row=0 } {

    # Now we know the row we are on, we can get
    # $CSV1[row], $CSV2[row], ...
    # Take the column variable array "CSV1", "CSV2", ..
    # Loop over them
    $rowContent = $columnVariables | ForEach {

        # $_ a string of the name, e.g. "CSV1"
        # Use Get-Variable to convert it
        # into the variable $CSV1
        # with -ValueOnly to get the array itself
        # rather than details about the variable
        $columnVar = Get-Variable -ValueOnly $_

        # $columVar is now one of the $CSVn variables
        # so it contains, e.g. 1,2,3,4
        # Index into that for the current row
        # to get one item, e.g. 3
        # Output it into the pipeline
        ($columnVar)[$row]

        } # This is the end of the inner loop
          # The pipeline now contains the column
          # values/content making up a single row
          # 1
          # 10
          # 'a'

    # Back in the outer row loop, Take the row
    # content and make it a comma separated string
    # e.g. "1,10,a"
    # Output this into the pipeline
    @($rowContent) -join ','

    # Increment the row counter
    $row++
}
```